# What is the most efficient way to find out which subnet an IP belongs to

Tags: algorithm, scala, data-structures, ip-address, trie

Suppose I have billions of records that contain IPv4 field each. And I want to find out:

1. If each record belongs to one of the subnet I concerns
2. Which subnet it belongs to if it satisfies requirement 1.

Each concerned subnet is defined as several masks(61.232.85.0/25, 61.232.86.0/27) and maybe some discrete IPs, and I have a total number of 1000 subnet definitions to deal with.

So, What's the most efficient algorithm and/or data structure to handle the job?

Also, I've find [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) a possible solution, any suggestions?

Comment: You could represent the subnets as int values, put them all in an array, sort it and then use a binary search on that. That would take a maximum of 10 steps to find a subnet. A trie might take e.g. 25 steps for a /25 subnet.

Comment: Also remember that 1000 ints is only 4 kb. That will easily fit into the CPU cache, making it really fast. And of course you could then use a second array that stores which subnet each of the masks belongs to.

Comment: @SpiderPig, thank you for your advice, I find it more efficient than Trie because subnets themselves are disjoint. Do you mind post it as an answer therefore I can up-vote, at the same time, more people could see later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could represent the subnets as int values, put them all in an array, sort it and then use a binary search on that.
Although longs might be better since then you don't have to deal with negative numbers in the binary search.
That would take a maximum of 10 steps to find a subnet. A trie might take e.g. 25 steps for a /25 subnet.
Also remember that 1000 longs is only 8 kb. That will easily fit into the CPU cache, making it really fast.
And of course you could then use a second array that stores which subnet each of the masks belongs to.

Here is an example in Scala
`findMaskIdx` finds the index of a given mask (the ip part of the subnet definition) using a binary search.
If it can't find anything it returns the index of the first mask that's larger than the one it searched for.
`findIpIdx` takes an ip address and returns the index of the subnet definition it belongs to or -1 if nothing is found.

`findIpIdx` can be run around 100 to 200 million times per second.
So it seems to be quite fast.
There is only one problem with this approach. If two subnets of different size overlap the code might find the wrong one.
But I hope that shouldn't be too difficult to fix.

```
def ipStringToInt(s: String): Int = {
  var ip = 0
  for(num <- s.split("\\.")) {
    ip = ip * 256 + num.toInt
  }
  ip
}

def parseSubnet(s: String): (Long, Int) = {
  val mask_length = s.split("/")
  val length = if(mask_length.size > 1) mask_length(1).toInt else 32
  var mask = ipStringToInt(mask_length(0)) & 0xFFFFFFFFL
  (mask, length)
}

val subnetGroups = Vector(
  Vector("61.232.85.0/25", "61.232.86.0/27"),
  Vector("123.234.12.24/16", "1.2.3.4"),
  Vector("61.232.87.5", "253.2.0.0/16")
)

val subnetData = (for {
  (group, idx) <- subnetGroups.zipWithIndex
  maskString <- group
  (mask, length) = parseSubnet(maskString)
} yield (mask, length, idx)).sortBy(_._1)

val masks: Array[Long] = subnetData.map(_._1).toArray
val maskLengths: Array[Int] = subnetData.map(_._2).toArray
val groupNr: Array[Int] = subnetData.map(_._3).toArray

def findMaskIdx(ip: Long): Int = {
  var low = 0
  var high = masks.size
  while(high > low) {
    val mid = (low + high)/2
    if(masks(mid) > ip) high = mid
    else if(masks(mid) < ip) low = mid + 1
    else return mid
  }
  low
}

def findIpIdx(ip: Int): Int = {
  val ipLong = ip & 0xFFFFFFFFL
  var idx = findMaskIdx(ipLong)
  if(idx < masks.size && masks(idx) == ipLong) return idx
  idx -= 1
  if(idx < 0) return -1
  val m = (0xFFFFFFFF00000000L >>> maskLengths(idx)) & 0xFFFFFFFFL
  if((m & masks(idx)) == (m & ipLong)) return idx
  return -1
}


println("subnet data (mask, bit length of mask, index of subnet group):")
println(subnetData.map {
  case (mask, length, idx) => (mask.toHexString, length, idx)
})
println()

println("masks = " + masks.toVector.map(_.toHexString))
println()

def testIP(ipString: String) {
  println("ipString = " + ipString)
  val ip = ipStringToInt(ipString)
  val dataIdx = findIpIdx(ip)
  println("dataIdx = " + dataIdx)
  if(dataIdx >= 0) {
    val data = subnetData(dataIdx)
    println("data = " + (subnetData(dataIdx) match {
      case (mask, length, idx) => (mask.toHexString, length, idx)
    }))
  }
  println()
}

testIP("61.232.86.12")
testIP("253.2.100.253")
testIP("253.3.0.0")
```

Answer (score -4):

That is real easy.  Convert the IP to an unsigned 32 integer.  Then if (IP1 & Mask) = (IP2 & Mask), where mask is the smaller of the two masks.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string IP1str = "61.232.85.0/25";
            cIP IP1 = new cIP(IP1str);
            string IP2str = "61.232.86.0/27";
            cIP IP2 = new cIP(IP2str);
            string IP3str = "61.232.85.0/22";
            cIP IP3 = new cIP(IP3str);
            string IP4str = "61.232.86.0/22";
            cIP IP4 = new cIP(IP4str);

            bool sameNet = (new cIP()).InSubnet(IP3str, IP4str);
        }
    }
    public class cIP
    {
        public UInt32 IP { get; set; }
        public string IPHex { get; set; }
        public UInt32 mask { get; set; }
        public string maskHex = "";

        public cIP(){}

        public cIP(string IPstr)
        {
            //remove mask
            string maskStr = IPstr.Substring(IPstr.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            mask = (UInt32)(Math.Pow(2, 32) - Math.Pow(2, 32 - UInt32.Parse(maskStr)));
            maskHex = mask.ToString("x8");
            IPstr = IPstr.Substring(0,IPstr.LastIndexOf("/"));
            string[] IParray = IPstr.Split(new char[] { '.' });
            for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                IP = IP + (UInt32.Parse(IParray[3 - i]) << (i * 8));
            }
            IPHex = IP.ToString("x8");
        }
        public bool InSubnet(string IP1str, string IP2str)
        {
            bool results = false;
            cIP IP1 = new cIP(IP1str);
            cIP IP2 = new cIP(IP2str);

            if (IP1.mask <= IP2.mask)
            {
                results = (IP1.IP & IP1.mask) == (IP2.IP & IP1.mask);
            }
            else
            {
                results = (IP1.IP & IP2.mask) == (IP2.IP & IP2.mask);
            }

            return results;
        }
        public bool InSubnet(cIP IP1, cIP IP2)
        {
            bool results = false;
            if (IP1.mask <= IP2.mask)
            {
                results = (IP1.IP & IP1.mask) == (IP2.IP & IP1.mask);
            }
            else
            {
                results = (IP1.IP & IP2.mask) == (IP2.IP & IP2.mask);
            }

            return results;
        }

    }

}
​
```

Comment: Have you considered the amount of data I mentioned in my question? I think the question might changed when faced with that massive data.

Comment: The conversion doesn't take that long.  It looks like your input is a string.  If it was an IP address it would be faster.